# Only one option can be selected with html multiple select form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a multiple select form that looks like this:

```
<select multiple="multiple" id="id_form-0-project" name="form-0-project">
    <option value="0">and another test</option>
    <option value="1">another test</option>
    <option value="2" selected="selected">one more test</option>
    <option value="3">test project</option>
</select>
```

As one can see, there is one selected value. This is always the first option that I select. However, when I select multiple options with shift click or command click, the newly selected items are not adjusted so as to contain the selected="selected" attribute, even though visually, it appears to the user that said selections are highlighted.

In this respect it is acting like a single selector, but I figured that adding the "multiple="multiple" attribute would allow for assigning the selected attribute to multiple options.

Is this a common problem? Could it have something to do with page reloading? What is the expected behavior?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> ...the newly selected items are not adjusted so as to contain the selected="selected" attribute...

Right. You'll also note that the `value` attribute on an `input` isn't updated when the user updates its value (e.g., if you look at `outerHTML`).

This is just how things work. It's not a bug or something you're doing wrong. The runtime state of the control just isn't reflected in the HTML attribute model of the element.

> What is the expected behavior?

This is the expected behavior. If you want to know which items are selected, don't look for attributes, look at the `selected` *property* (not attribute) of the option.

If you want an array of the *selected* `HTMLOptionElement` instances:

```
var selected = Array.prototype.filter.call($("id_form-0-project")[0].options, function(option) {
    return option.selected;
});
```

If you want the actual values, combine it with `.map`:

```
var selected = Array.prototype.filter.call($("#id_form-0-project")[0].options, function(option) {
    return option.selected;
}).map(function(option) {
    return option.value;
});
```

You can, of course, easily wrap that up into your own minimal jQuery plugin:

```
jQuery.fn.selectedValues = function() {
    if (!this[0] || !this[0].options) {
        return undefined;
    }
    return Array.prototype.filter.call(this[0].options, function(option) {
        return option.selected;
    }).map(function(option) {
        return option.value;
    });
};
```

then

```
var values = $("#id_form-0-project").selectedValues();
```

---

Your (good) question highlights one of the (many) dark corners of how the DOM and HTML serialization and browsers have evolved over the years. No one would have *designed* this. :-) And yet, quirks and all, it works surprisingly well.

Comment: Ok thank you this is good to know. I am ultimately trying to get a list of all the selected items so I can identically select other forms with the same options. Before I was using the $( "#id_form-0-project" ).find(":selected").val() || [] approach but looks like I will have to try something else.

Comment: @Malonge: Perfectly reasonable approach, it just doesn't work. :-) I've added a couple of ideas to the answer for how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Since you tagged with `jQuery`:

While the attribute on the HTML tag itself isn't updated, the value of the `selected` property is updated to be consistent with the UI.

You can still accurately determine which items are selected using `$(element).prop('selected')` as in the example:

http://jsfiddle.net/17s4q7ht/

HTML:

```
<select multiple="multiple" id="id_form-0-project" name="form-0-project">
    <option value="0">and another test</option>
    <option value="1">another test</option>
    <option value="2" selected="selected">one more test</option>
    <option value="3">test project</option>
</select>
<div id="status"></div>
```

JS:

```
$('#id_form-0-project').on('change', function() {
    $('#status').text($(this).find('option').map(function(i, e){
        return $(e).val() + " is " + ($(e).prop('selected') ? "" : "not ") + "selected";
    }).get().join('; '));
});
```

Comment: You read my mind. I did include the jQuery tag for this very reason. I need to find out which options are selected so I can make identical selections to another form. I think this will help do the trick.